# VS Code integrated terminal is messing up the clipboard python code when pasting

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code, terminal, windows-10

In a clean installation of VS Code (1.59.1) the code pasted in the integrated terminal has a different indentation than the one available in the editor. I tried changing the parameter `"editor.formatOnPaste": true` and there was no improvement. This problem does not exist when I copy the same content and paste it into the powershell or command prompt. Any ideas on how to solve this?

[image: error description]

[image]

Comment: I tried a lot, but I can't reproduce your problem. Could you try to create some other python file and add some other code then copy it to the IPython?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to reproduce your problem on Linux (bash, tmux, zsh, etc.) and Windows (PowerShell, Command Prompt, etc.) without much success.

I am willing to bet it is a problem with the 'ipython' you are running in PS.

Have you tried installing a different Python version just to see if that is the issue?

Comment: Did you try it with VS code? I see such problem only in VS code terminal (PowerShell or CMD). Standalone PowerShell or CMD are okay.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to import and initialize ipython or you have given an extra space.

Comment: I tried to recreate it but it is not happening.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: What do you mean " import and initialize ipython"? Call "import IPython" inside of ipython intepreter? I donot think it is needed, because everything is fine in standalone powershell or CMD. However in VS code integrated terminal I can reproduce problem very easily.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce your problem myself, but here are some solutions I think they might work.

I believe the source of this problem may have something to do with  **Ipython's automatic indentation** when working with the vscode version you are using. You could use **Ipython's built-in magic command**: `%autoindent` to turn off the automatic indentation.

Just run the magic command: `%autoindent` and you will see in your prompt the message:

`Automatic indentation is: OFF` (You can run it again to turn it back on if you want)

After that you should be able to copy and paste your code (keeping the original indentation) and Ipython won't add new indentation.

Another solution is using the **magic command**: `%paste`  This command paste and execute the code from clipboard ([here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.terminal.magics.html#IPython.terminal.magics.TerminalMagics.paste) you can find more information about this command).

If you want to edit the code in the prompt before executing it, remember you can use: `%cpaste` instead.

Comment: I some how can reproduce the problem. %autoindent didnot help,  %paste worked. Thanks! I suspect prompt_toolkit clashes with VS code... Becasue there is no problems when ipython is run directly from  PowerShell / CMD (not integrated VS code terminal).

Answer (score 0):

Considering the fact that no one can reproduce the problem, I suspect you might have inconsistent space/tab (or other) characters with the file itself.

To check if this is the case, try making a **new python file in VS Code** and rewriting the original code in it (do not copy-paste). If it works, it was just an issue certain characters in the file: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57206412) may help for larger files where re-writing is not an option.

If this didn't work, try now making another **new python file in a different text editor** and rewriting the original code in it (again, do not copy-paste). Run it through the CMD or powershell. If this doesn't work, it's not VS Code's fault (may be an issue with your python/ipython configuration/installation).

If it still hasn't worked, you might want to try running the newest file (created in another text editor) through VS Code, or running the original file you have through the CMD/powershell (not copy-paste), and diagnosing from there.

Comment: I can reproduce it very easily (VS 163.2). And I do not have problems when running ipython outside of VS (e.g., directly from powershell). And there is no space / tab confusion, which can be easily checked by using Notepad++. Maybe this is issue only with a specific ipython version?

Comment: I am using ipython 7.27.0